# How to resize shapes drawn on map based on zoom value with react-native-maps

Tags: javascript, google-maps, react-native, react-native-maps

I am using `react-native-maps` to integrate maps in my application. I want to show some sort of radar heading the direction the user is heading, i want to area covered of different distances like 1 km, 5 km, and 10 km. resulting in something like the image below.

[image: The desire result]

My initial solution was to draw shapes using `View` with position absolute,
i got something like this with the approach.

[image]

The problem with above approach is `View` height is static, and it doesn't respond to zoom value of the map, also the calculation of `View` height with respect to distance is non trivial.

My second solution was to draw circles around user marker of certain radius, rather then a full circle, i can create semi circles or semi-semi circles achieve the desire result. But i cannot find any way to draw semi circle with the library `react-native-maps`.

Any suggestion how can i achieve the desire result?

Answer (score 0):

Your first solution seems good enough to me, maybe a little modifications should get you the result you are looking for, follow along:

1. First lets associate all the relevant `<View />` styling props to state values

```
// ... all your imports and other code

state ={
    viewHeight: 0, // or any default value you want
    viewWidth: 0, // or any default value you want

    // ... other view parameters used and other state values
}

// ... functions and other code

render() {
    return (
        // ... other rendered components etc

        <View
            style={{
                width: this.state.viewWidth,
                height: this.state.viewHeight
            }} />
    )
}
```

1. Next we will get the map zoom level every time it changes and preform some sort of conditions

```
<MapView
    ref='map'                                       // <==== add the ref map so we can access the zoom level from our _onMapChange function later
    style={{ flex: 1 }}
    provider={PROVIDER_GOOGLE}                      // <==== this approach will not work on apple maps as the camera will not give us the zoom parameter so use google maps
    onRegionChange={() => this._onMapChange()} />   // <==== this will tell the map to fire the _onMapChange() function everytime there is a change to the map region
```

3. The `_onMapChange()` function:

```
_onMapChange = async () => {
    const {
        zoom,
        pitch,
        center,
        heading 
    } = await this.refs.map.getCamera();

    // Now set the conditions for the view style based on the zoom level, maybe something like this:

    if (zoom <= 5) {
        this.setState({
            viewWidth: 50,  // what ever width you want to set
            viewHeight: 50  // what ever height you want to set
            // ... other view parameters
        })
    } else if (zoom <= 10) {
        this.setState({
            viewWidth: 100,  // what ever width you want to set
            viewHeight: 100  // what ever height you want to set
            // ... other view parameters
        })
    }
}
```

**Heads-Up: I am using my editor that's all so there might be some syntax errors**

Hope this Helps!

Comment: Thanks for the response, its sounds like a good solution but i think is not, the reason being i want the height of view or the edge the view to be at "1km from my current location", how i can convert km to px with respect to zoom value, thats a lot of calculation.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Overlay (circle, polygon) or can make your custom overlay to cover certain areas on the map.

Like this,

[image: Image1]
[image: Image2]

**Link for overlay docs: [react-native-community/react-native-maps](https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-maps)**

To make it dynamic, precisely calculate longitudeDelta and LatitudeDelta.